# How to Fetch all Permission of Role in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I want to fetch all permission of a particular role, I tried using ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil but it only fetches permission which is inside role.

```
System.out.println("userGroupGroupRole:::" + userGroupGroupRole);
List<ResourcePermission> listOfPermission = new 
ArrayList<ResourcePermission>();
for (UserGroupGroupRole uggrole : userGroupGroupRole) {
    listOfPermission
        .addAll(ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.getRoleResourcePermissions(uggrole.getRoleId()));

    System.out.println("Title::" + uggrole.getRole().getTitle(locale));
    System.out.println("Site:::" + uggrole.getGroup().getGroupKey());
    System.out.println("user-group:::::" + uggrole.getUserGroup().getName());
}

System.out.println("listOfPermission::" + listOfPermission);
```

Fetches Permission See Picture Which Roles are fetched :

[image]

I Need this Permission shown below picture.
These Permissions I want to get :

[image]

Comment: It's not so clear what you mean with "I want to fetch all permission of a particular role"..

Comment: Suppose I created one regular role for example role_a. In role_a in we can set permissions by clicking on the 3 dots and permission tab, I need those permissions.

Comment: See I attach another image which I want to get permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Way we can fetch all permission

```
PortletConfigurationPermissionsDisplayContext portletConfigurationPermissionsDisplayContext = new PortletConfigurationPermissionsDisplayContext(
            request, renderRequest);

    Resource resource = portletConfigurationPermissionsDisplayContext.getResource();

    if (Validator.isNotNull(portletConfigurationPermissionsDisplayContext.getModelResource())) {
        PortalUtil.addPortletBreadcrumbEntry(request,
                HtmlUtil.unescape(portletConfigurationPermissionsDisplayContext.getSelResourceDescription()),
                null);
        PortalUtil.addPortletBreadcrumbEntry(request, LanguageUtil.get(request, "permissions"), currentURL);
    }
    System.out.println("Resource::" + resource);

    boolean role_a_hasPermissionToView = false;
    List<Role> allRoles = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRoles(0, RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRolesCount());
    //System.out.println(allRoles + "-all roles");
    for (Role role : allRoles) {


                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
                String rolename = role.getName();
                System.out.println("Primary Key::" + role.getPrimaryKey() + "----Role Name::" + rolename);
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

                List<String> currentIndividualActions1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> currentGroupActions1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> currentGroupTemplateActions1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> currentCompanyActions1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                ResourcePermissionUtil.populateResourcePermissionActionIds(
                        portletConfigurationPermissionsDisplayContext.getGroupId(), role, resource,
                        portletConfigurationPermissionsDisplayContext.getActions(), currentIndividualActions1,
                        currentGroupActions1, currentGroupTemplateActions1, currentCompanyActions1);

                for (String action : portletConfigurationPermissionsDisplayContext.getActions()) {
                    System.out.println("action::" + action);
                    System.out
                            .println("Resource Action Util:" + ResourceActionsUtil.getAction(request, action));
                    if (action.equals(ActionKeys.ACCESS_IN_CONTROL_PANEL)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    boolean checked1 = false;

                    if (currentIndividualActions1.contains(action) || currentGroupActions1.contains(action)
                            || currentGroupTemplateActions1.contains(action)
                            || currentCompanyActions1.contains(action)) {
                        checked1 = true;
                    }

                    String preselectedMsg = StringPool.BLANK;

                    if (currentGroupActions1.contains(action)
                            || currentGroupTemplateActions1.contains(action)) {
                        preselectedMsg = "x-is-allowed-to-do-action-x-in-all-items-of-type-x-in-x";
                    } else if (currentCompanyActions1.contains(action)) {
                        preselectedMsg = "x-is-allowed-to-do-action-x-in-all-items-of-type-x-in-this-portal-instance";
                    }

                    List<String> guestUnsupportedActions1 = portletConfigurationPermissionsDisplayContext
                            .getGuestUnsupportedActions();

                    boolean disabled1 = false;

                    if (rolename.equals(RoleConstants.GUEST) && guestUnsupportedActions1.contains(action)) {
                        disabled1 = true;
                    }

                    String dataMessage = StringPool.BLANK;

                    if (Validator.isNotNull(preselectedMsg)) {
                        String type1 = portletConfigurationPermissionsDisplayContext
                                .getSelResourceDescription();

                        if (Validator.isNull(type1)) {
                            type1 = ResourceActionsUtil.getModelResource(locale, resource.getName());
                        }

                        dataMessage = HtmlUtil.escapeAttribute(LanguageUtil.format(request, preselectedMsg,
                                new Object[]{role.getTitle(locale),
                                        ResourceActionsUtil.getAction(request, action), type1,
                                        HtmlUtil.escape(portletConfigurationPermissionsDisplayContext
                                                .getGroupDescriptiveName())},
                                false));
                    }

                    String actionSeparator = Validator.isNotNull(preselectedMsg)
                            ? ActionUtil.PRESELECTED
                            : ActionUtil.ACTION;
                    System.out.println("Checked:::" + checked1);

                } //for loops ends here

    } //loops end here
```

[This Permission Fetches[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll03i.png)